# how to cast pandas.DataFrame into gviz_api.DataTable

Tags: api, pandas, google-visualization

I've got a pandas.DataFrame object that I'd like to cast into a gviz_api.DataTable which I'll then use in my google charts.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any straightforward way to cast a pandas dataframe into a gviz data table.

Here's how I do it:-

```
from gviz_data_table import Table   # using https://bitbucket.org/charlie_x/gviz-data-table though you should probably use the official google one.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "time" : [1,2,3,4,5],
    "temp" : np.random.rand(5)
})

table = Table()
table.add_column('temp', float, 'Temp')
table.add_column('time', float, 'Time')

for row in df.iterrows():
    table.append(row[1].tolist())

table.rows

[OrderedDict([('temp', <gviz_data_table.cell.Cell object at 0x104a64aa0>), ('time', <gviz_data_table.cell.Cell object at 0x104a64a50>)]),
 OrderedDict([('temp', <gviz_data_table.cell.Cell object at 0x104a64af0>), ('time', <gviz_data_table.cell.Cell object at 0x104a64b40>)]),
 OrderedDict([('temp', <gviz_data_table.cell.Cell object at 0x104a64b90>), ('time', <gviz_data_table.cell.Cell object at 0x104a64be0>)]),
 OrderedDict([('temp', <gviz_data_table.cell.Cell object at 0x104a64c30>), ('time', <gviz_data_table.cell.Cell object at 0x104a64c80>)]),
 OrderedDict([('temp', <gviz_data_table.cell.Cell object at 0x104a64cd0>), ('time', <gviz_data_table.cell.Cell object at 0x104a64d20>)])]
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using iterrows and lists you can use .values to get the dataframe as a numpy object (an array of arrays - one for each row)

To finish the process and turn this into a GViz Table

- set up the description
- use gviz_api's LoadData() method to load the values.

Code Example

```
#set up Google Table w/ the description
gpa_desc=[("grade_date", "date", "Date" ),
          ("gpa", "number", "GPA")]
gpa_data_table=gviz_api.DataTable(gpa_desc)

#your df as a numpy object
gpa_values=df_gpa.values

#populate the table with your data 
gpa_data_table.LoadData(gpa_values)

#convert to json to pass to the view
gpa_json=gpa_data_table.ToJSon()
```